# How to interpret S3 Usage report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My AWS account is compromised and in-between the time there are two records relevant to my S3

```
AmazonS3    ListAllMyBuckets    Requests-Tier1      01/12/16 20:00:00   01/12/16 21:00:00           2
AmazonS3    ListAllMyBuckets    DataTransfer-Out-Bytes      01/12/16 20:00:00   01/12/16 21:00:00   1046
```

How can I interpret this ? Is this a proof the attacker hasn't grabbed my data, only have a look at them ?

What does "Requests-Tier1" and "DataTransfer-Out-Bytes" mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tier 1 Requests are list requests and `PUT` requests.

Tier 2 Requests are `GET` and all other requests except `DELETE`.

`DataTransfer-Out-Bytes` is bytes sent outbound from S3.

If this is all you have, it *suggests*, though does not exhaustively *prove* that someone merely looked at your buckets but didn't download anything... or that you, yourself, looked at the buckets in the console.

http://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/common/amz-storage-usage-type-help.html